# Reverse Functions

Tags: functions

I am doing some revision and trying to understand the functions I have done the A and B questions but got stock on the last one

The functions 
$$g : \{a, b, c\} \mapsto \{1, 2\}$$ and 
$$f : \{1, 2\} \mapsto \{a, b, c\}$$
 are given by 
$$g(a) = 1$$
$$g(b) = 2$$
$$g(c) = 2$$
$$f(1) = c$$
$$f(2) = b$$

A. Classify each of $f$ and $g$ as bijective, injective, surjective, or neither.

B. Find $g$ of $f$.

C. Either find the inverse of $g$ of $f$ or explain why $g$ of $f$ is not invertible.

I believe that the answer to the B is :
$$g(f(1) = g (c) = 2$$
$$g(f(2) = g (b) = 2$$

Just need some help with C

Comment: A-question should help you with answering C-question. What do you know about the functions that are invertible? What properties from A-question they must have?

Comment: dont really understand much but for part A I got G as surjective and and F as injective

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A function $F$ is bijective if and only if $F$ is injective and surjective.

Let's apply this to your problem:

- $f$ is not surjective since there is no element in $\{1, 2\}$ such that its image is $a$. Therefore, $f$ is not bijective.
- $g$ is not inyective since there are two elements ($b$ and $c$) with the same image ($2$). Then, we can conclude that $g$ is not bijective.

Comment: I guess I was totally wrong about A. Was my B answered correctly ?

Comment: Yes, It is correct.

Comment: sorry but i still dont understand the the answer to question C

Comment: What do you don't understand exactly?

Comment: i dont know the correct answer for the C part. The answer above is for the A part right ?

Comment: The answer I gave is for part C.